# ZedGraph C# Отображать только положительные оси

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Можно ли сделать в ZedGraph координатную плоскость только с положительными осями?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Чтобы отображалась 1 четверть координатной плоскости(не было отрицательных значений).

Comment: `pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0; pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;`

Comment: Такой метод не подходит, при масштабирования графика пользователем(колесиком) все равно буду отображаться отрицательные оси.

Comment: Отслеживайте масштабирование и корректируйте видимую область